# multiple SVG zoom and pan at once same piece

Tags: html, svg

there are svg zoom and pan for one SVG tag in one HTML. say, if i have 2-3 SVG which are running overlay layers and wanted to have them zoom and pan all together at once, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to manipulate SVG's in whole, or individual parts of an SVG if it's inline and marked up with classes.

Try using the CSS transform and animation properties...

```
.svg1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  animation: panZoom 10s linear 1;
}

@keyframes panZoom {
  0%   {transform: translateX(0) scale(1);}
  100% {transform: translateX(1000px) scale(3);}
}
```